# Appsync GraphQL api Authorization with oidc

Tags: graphql, authorization, aws-appsync

I am using **OIDC protocol** for authentication in **Appsync**. For **authorization/role management** I am using a custom server which I am calling from an **Appsync function**. The problem here is, if I do the **authorization** part, all of the the resolvers should be turned into **PIPELINE**. In my opinion that's a bad design. I was wondering if there is any **alternative way** to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AppSync supports OpenID Connect as an authorization mechanism, you don't need to validate the JWT token yourself in a function. Is there a use case for which you need to do that?

Also, what you described by using pipeline resolvers where the first function validates the authorization information is the current recommended way for doing this.